# asp.net show message and return which button selected

Tags: asp.net, alert

i have a gridview and set autogenerate=true
i want when the user click on the row gridview and run the selectedindexchanged event ,in selectedindexchange event show to user a simple alert dialog,for example:
Are you sure to delete this items?
Yes No
and when user click on Yes button start other process for example start database delete t-sql.
How can i do this?
thanks.
i use this tutorial:
[tutorial](http://www.webreference.com/js/column116/4.html)
and this tutorial show messagebox successfully,but messagebox dialog show background of my web! want show on my web page.

Comment: you need to to this on client side using javascript.

Comment: @Robert how can i?please explain

Comment: you need to listen for specific events in table (grid view client side representation) and then handle the events, show alert, if OK is clicked, do the manual postback. You should read something about grid view and client side.

Comment: @Robert thank Robert,do you have tutorial link?

Comment: I found something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428868.aspx This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428868.aspx

on how to Add Client-Side Confirmation when Deleting